# Connect Signal emited from method Class into different Class Slot Custom Signals PySide

Tags: python, signals, pyqt4, pyside, signals-slots

I want to connect the signal emitted from closeWidgetUI class method into addTool class method. But this seems only to work with PyQt4 not with PySide. Every time I hit the closeButton created in         self.close_btn.clicked.connect(self.closeWidgetUI), the program freeze and close itself. Any sugestion?

```
import PySide.QtCore as qc
import PySide.QtGui  as qg

class InterpolateIt(dc,qg.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        qg.QDialog.__init__(self)

        """ MORE THINGS 
        OVER THIS PART NOT IMPORTANT AT MOMENT"""

        add_button.clicked.connect(self.addTool)

    def addTool(self):

        #NEED TO CONNECT closeWidgetUI EMITED SIGNAL HERE 
        new_widget = InterpolateWidget()
        self.clicked.connect(new_widget, qc.SIGNAL('CLOSE'), self.removeTool)

    def removeTool(self,interpWidget):
        self.interpolateLayout.removeWidget(interpWidget)
        interpWidget.deleteLater()


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#        
class InterpolateWidget(qg.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        qg.QFrame.__init__(self)

        """ MORE THINGS 
        OVER THIS PART NOT IMPORTANT AT MOMENT"""

        # HERE BUTTON EMIT SIGNAL AT CLICKED
        self.close_btn.clicked.connect(self.closeWidgetUI)

        # TRIGGER THIS FUNC
    def closeWidgetUI(self):
        self.emit(qc.SIGNAL('CLOSE'), self)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial

 def addTool(self):

        #NEED TO CONNECT closeWidgetUI EMITED SIGNAL HERE 
        new_widget = InterpolateWidget()
        deleteTool = partial(self.removeTool,new_widget)
        new_widget.close_btn.clicked.connect(deleteTool)
```

i did it in this way! thanks to my brain :) cheers